# How to handle font size on different type of resolution

Tags: flutter

I am developing on a Pixel 2 simulator and of course, the font size that I use are very good for that phone.

When going on a iPhone 5S, I was expecting to see the font size to be reduced and be proportional to that screen resolution. Maybe Flutter does something, but is it not easy to see at the first place.

I found 'flutter_screenutil' plugin, but not working as expected. Probably because I don't put the right values for the `ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334)..init(context);` The values are the 'screen size of the device in the design' of a iphone 6 (based on the example).

If I use the plugin with font size 100 on my Blackberry Motion(1080x1794), the result is what I expect. Using the same code with an iphone 6(750x1334), I should use font size 70. Not very useful.

Anybody has a nice way to handle the font size for different resolution without changing the font size value put in the code?

Comment: You can customize your font size based on width and height of the screen. Use MediaQUery to find out what is screen size: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html

Comment: Or check out textScaleFactor.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Google fonts. As Flutter works with custom fonts and you can apply a custom font across an entire app or to individual widgets. I was not able to see any issues while running ‘Pacifico’ family with font size 20. I also tested the following test code on Pixel 3 and Iphone 11, and do not see any issues.

Steps are simple as described in the flutter documentation:

1. Import the font files.
2. Declare the font in the pubspec. In may case I downloaded the
   Pacifico from https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Pacifico?selection.family=Pacifico
3. Use a font in a specific widget.

My pubspec.yaml file:

`flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Pacifico
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf`

My main.dart file :

```
` Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   title: 'Font test',
   home: Scaffold(
     backgroundColor: Colors.white,
     body: SafeArea(
       child: Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           Container(
             height: 100.0,
             width: 100.0,
             color: Colors.red,
             child: Text(
               'container one',
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                 fontSize: 20.0,
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Container(
             height: 100.0,
             width: 100.0,
             color: Colors.blue,
             child: Text(
               'container two',
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                 fontSize: 20.0,
               ),
             ),
           ),
           Container(
             height: 100.0,
             width: 100.0,
             color: Colors.purple,
             child: Text(
               'container three',
               style: TextStyle(
                 fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                 fontSize: 20.0,
               ),
             ),
           ),

         ],
       ),
     ),
   )
 );
}
```

If you are having any issues with the  fonts let me know, Also, as you see it’s the basic sample app. I would appreciate if you can help me out with the code sample to reproduce the issue. I do not have my Mac machine to help you with the screen shot. I will update this thread with the screen shot, once I have my Maclaptop