# How to disable ligatures in fonts in Flutter

Tags: text, flutter, fonts, truetype, ligature

I have a custom font, in which my "fi" is replaced with "r". Do you have any idea how to disable ligatures in my fonts in Flutter?

Comment: Have you added your custom font correctly?

Comment: I think so. Like this: 

  fonts:
  - family: Cond
    fonts:
      - asset: fonts/Cond-Regular.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Cond-Bold.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Cond-Bold-Italic.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Cond-Italic.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Cond-Light-Italic.ttf
      - asset: fonts/Cond-Light.ttf

Comment: Added it to the text style of the Text widget?

Comment: No, to pubspeck.yaml . font in Material App just   fontFamily: 'Cond',

Comment: Could you let me know which custom font you are using? You can try using Google fonts. As Flutter works with custom fonts and you can apply a custom font across an entire app or to individual widgets. I was not able to see any issues while running ‘Pacifico’ family with font size 20. 

You can check more info on this thread : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041520/how-to-handle-font-size-on-different-type-of-resolution?answertab=active#tab-top
If you are still having issues, then please help with your pubspec.yaml and Dart file.

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed how to [add custom font](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) in your entire Flutter app, there shouldn't be any problem.

> Flutter works with custom fonts and you can apply a custom font across
> an entire app or to individual widgets. This recipe creates an app
> that uses custom fonts with the following steps:
>
> 1. Import the font files.
> 2. Declare the font in the pubspec.
> 3. Set a font as the default.
> 4. Use a font in a specific widget.

If this is not the case, try to provide a [a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).