# Flutter Text widgets omit sequence "ff" when displaying value

Tags: flutter, textinput

I have a problem in Flutter displaying Strings that contain character sequence **"ff"**. It is reproducible both with **Text** and **TextInput** widget in several different cases (string value hardcoded, string stored as a constant, string read from JSON file,...).

Simple example to illustrate:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Difficulty and take off");
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Text("Difficulty and take off"),
        ));
  }
```

This gets displayed as **"Diculty and take o"**:
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be0dI.jpg)

However, print command correctly displays it in the console.
Also if I use **RichText** widget it also displays correctly:

```
RichText(text: TextSpan(text: "Difficulty and take off", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)))
```

While using RichText all over the app is a possible workaround (although not a very nice one), I still have no idea how to solve the problem with TextInput. When a user types the "ff" sequence, it just disappears.

I'm building my app on Windows 10 using Android Studio 4.0.1.
So far I've tried:

- using different devices (Samsung, Huawei) -> all the same
- upgrading flutter to 2.2.1 -> same

When debugging in Android Studio, the field value is correct (contains the "ff" char sequence), it just doesn't get displayed on the screen.

I have a deadline for production release in 14 days and I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
flutter --version
Flutter 2.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 02c026b03c (11 days ago) • 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
Engine • revision 0fdb562ac8
Tools • Dart 2.13.1
```

Comment: I don't know Flutter, but it's probably because your font has ligatures enabled, so `ff` is actually `ﬀ` (one single character), and maybe the font doesn't have such code (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56523423/5160230)). Can you try with another font and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Which font you are using? It seems like the font you are using don't have any implementation of 'f' 'F'

Comment: I was using Gilroy font before, but now I've tried with Montserrat and it started displaying `ff`. Thank you very much!!