# Turn off ligatures in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to turn off the font ligatures for a text. I use the Fira Code font, but I can't find a way to turn off the ligatures in TextStyle in my app.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523423/how-to-disable-ligatures-in-fonts-in-flutter

Comment: @phuzi No, I've already seen that one. I want to disable these ligatures as in the picture. [example](https://imgur.com/a/WA0NPAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `Text` widget, you can enable or disable various [`FontFeature`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontFeature-class.html)s via its [`TextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextStyle-class.html).  Looking at [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) in https://wakamaifondue.com/, it appears ligatures are controlled by the `calt` feature, which is enabled by default.  You therefore could try disabling that:

```dart
Text(
  someString,
  style: TextStyle(fontFeatures: [FontFeature.disable('calt')]),
)
```

Alternatively, Fira Code is open-source and [has build options](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#building-fira-code-locally) to enable or disable features in the generated font files.